# Lightning: How to intercept doneRendering event for particular component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there usage like:

```
<aura:handler name="doneRendering" value="{!this}" action="{!c.ondoneRendering}"/>
```

Similar to init event handler from spec:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!.c.doInit}"/>
```

I've tried to use like `<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" value="{!this}" action="{!c.ondoneRendering}"/>` but `c.ondoneRendering` controller method is executed for all related component in the tree.

Comment: This is really the same as this question here. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72754/which-is-corresponding-event-in-lightning-component-vs-load-or-domcontentloaded

Answer (score 1):

Typically done in the renderer, can you just attach your logic to the afterRender function?